# work with ICollection and IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have some code expecting an `ICollection`. Now I want to devide that collection into smaller chunks by grouping them based on a given attribute (all elements within my collection are instances of an abstract base-class, however for legacy code we do not use the generic version of that interface). So what I´d like to achieve is to obtain any enumerable list of collections (one for every group). To get this I planned to convert the `ICollection` to the generic `IEnumerable<T>` using the `Cast<T>`-method on `ICollection`, and afterwards build a dictionary from that `IEnumerable<T>` using a LINQ-query. But I fell there might be some better approaches. Do you have any?

```
public override void DoSomething(ICollection features)
{
    var grp = features.Cast<MyBaseClass>().GroupBy(x => x.table);
    foreach(var g in grp) base.DoSomething(g);
}
```

EDIT: Hence the base-method (surely) has same signatur (also expects an instance of `ICollection`) how do I get the values of the groups back to the (non-generic) `ICollection`?

Comment: Provide us a code that you feel is not a better way. Also note you should ask such a question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Since you are considering LINQ: did you find the `.OfType<T>` extension method?

Comment: @CompuChip I noticed it but never used it. Great idea though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your approach, but there is one caveat: if the `ICollection` instance contains an element that is *not* of type `MyBaseClass`, you'll get a cast exception. You can work around this using the `OfType` extension method, which checks if the element is actually of the type and if so, it casts it to the target type. If the element is of a different type, it is just ignored and no exception is thrown.

```
public override void DoSomething(ICollection features)
{
    var grp = features.OfType<MyBaseClass>().GroupBy(x => x.table);
    foreach(var g in grp) base.DoSomething((ICollection)g.ToList());
}
```

You can see a working example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0VkedY

Of course, if your requirement is that all elements *must* be of a specific type, you should use `Cast` instead of `OfType`.

Comment: however, if you DO expect the data to be of a certain type, it would be better to use `Cast` to find any errors as soon as possible.